# Getting strings from resx into an array without looping - C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, resx

I want to read all the strings from a resx file and load it into an array without looping. I'm working in an asp.net web application and i'm using C#. How can i get the strings?

Thank you

NLV

Comment: What's your problem with looping?

Comment: Yes, maybe there is some library call or Linq statement somewhere, but they all, will implement some loop internally.

Comment: Why should i loop if we may have a possibility to do it without looping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string[] allStrings;
using (var reader = new ResXResourceReader(fileName))
{
    allStrings = reader.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Select(o => o.Value).OfType<string>().ToArray();
}
```

Comment: The `Reader.GetEnumerator` returns an `IDictionaryEnumerator`, so every item that is returned is a `DictionaryEntry`. This will never be of type `string`. I think you need: `Reader.Select(o => o.Value).OfType<string>().ToArray()`